# Proper naming scope for custom error handlers in Python

Tags: python, error-handling

I'm trying to write an error handling class for my application. Is it necessary to include the full path to the error handler every time? Below is my code.

appname/appname/model/error.py

```
class UserError(Exception):
  """ User errors
  """

  def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value

  def __str__(self):
    return repr(self.value)
```

My class function:

```
from error import UserError

def doSomething(
  """ Some function
  """
  if (value == 2):
    pass
  else:
    raise UserError('Value is not 2')
```

That is called from my application as follows:
from error import UserError

```
try:
  print names['first']
except appname.model.error.UserError as e:
  print e
```

When raised:

```
>> appname.model.error.UserError: 'No file specified'
```

Do I have to refer to this as "appname.model.error.UserError" all the time? Or is there a way to just refer to this error as UserError or even error.UserError? Where to I adjust the scope of this? Seems like not a good idea in case I change the directory structure (or even name) of my application, no?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
from appname.model.error import UserError
```